# Name " something " is not defined, Hello world program

Tags: python

This is my first program ever written in Python. I'm following a guide on youtube and I've done exactly the same as the guy in the video. Here's my code:

```
print("hello world")
myName = input ('what is your name')
print(myName)
```

It doesn't work I'm getting `name "something" is not defined`.
The guide I'm following can be found here: https://youtu.be/hFhiV5X5QM4?t=5m7s

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3? (You should be using Python3 unless you have a really good reason not to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're using was probably written with Python 3, and you're probably running Python 2.

As @Slayther points out, in Python 2, you should be using `raw_input` instead of `input`. (If you're just getting started, though, I would recommend just using Python 3!)

Comment: How do i change from 2.7 to 3 ? im useing visual studio and i have both versions installed, btw thanks for the answer i aint high enougth reputation to mark as answer tho

Comment: @SteffenCH you don't need rep to mark as an answer, you just need to ask a question. Why do you think you don't have enough rep to mark an answer? Upvoting (the uparrow) is not marking an answer - the check mark marks the answer

Comment: Any reputation can mark answer as accepted. Just click the tick on the left side of the answer.

Comment: @SteffenCH Unfortunately, I've never used Python with Visual Studio, so I'm not sure how to tell it which Python to use. :-( Maybe ask a separate question for that?

Comment: Actualy i just figured it out thanks alot guys, any tips on how to get started with python ? i come from basic stuffs in VB.NET C# and ive done a bit of database stuff ( just so u know where im standing )

Comment: @SteffenCH if searching google for "Visual studio change python version" doesn't provide a reasonable result in the top 10, I would definitely go ahead and ask another question.

Comment: @SteffenCH follow the [official python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) Once you get a few more rep here on SO you can join us in the [python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and we'll be happy to c̶o̶r̶r̶u̶p̶t̶ mold you ;)

Comment: Great thanks see you in there haha

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2**

Input evaluates what you type in. If you type in `something`, it will treat it as variable.

You should either type it with quotations `"something"`, use `raw_input` or switch to Python 3.

**Python 3**

`raw_input` is removed and `input`'s functionality is same as `raw_input` was in Python 2, so your code should work fine.

Comment: oh yeah ive tried with quotations also but that diddnt work either also it works for the guy in the video with the same code

Comment: Only in Python2. The tutorial video is definitely Python3

Comment: Ah, haven't checked the video. The brackets for print don't signify that it is indeed version 2, as it is supported syntax.

Comment: The behavior of the program in the video verify that it's Python3. At the *very* least you should be pointing out that there is a difference between Python2 and Python3, rather than just making a blanket statement.

Comment: Arh well that makes sence then i guess thanks!

Comment: @WayneWerner Yeah, I was asuming the problem was in using `input` and not in python version. It was odd to me that `input` wouldn't work in this manner in python 3, so I assumed it was python 2. Thanks for pointing that out.